# Why Partial<(param1: ParamType, ...) => ReturnType> behaves like any?

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation

Why does this code compile?

```
const fn: Partial<(a: string) => number> = "LOL DIS IS A STRING"; // any non-null value

// Though this won't compile under strict null checks:
const fn: Partial<(a: string) => number> = null;
const fn: Partial<(a: string) => number> = undefined;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=55#)

This issue arose when applying [`DeepPartial`](https://github.com/Veetaha/ts-typedefs/blob/beedfe4dd3f2d64499720071a7144753a937e6dc/lib/types/partial-required.ts#L8) to types with methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `Partial<(a: string) => number>` evaluates to `{}`, the empty object type, which is like `unknown` with `null` and `undefined` excluded.

Longer answer:

- `Partial<T>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) defined as `{[K in keyof T]?: T[K]}`. It iterates over properties of `T` and makes each of them optional.  In this case, though, `keyof ((a: string)=>number)` is `never`; it has no properties.  (Well, function types *do* have properties from the `Function` interface, such as `bind`, `call`, `length`, etc., and properties from the `Object` interface, such as `toString` and `valueOf`, etc.  But these properties are generally not useful to iterate over, so they are suppressed.)  So `Partial<(a: string)=>number>` returns an object type with no properties: the empty type `{}`.
- The empty type `{}` acts almost like [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type), in that [nearly everything is assignable to it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces).  That's because object types in TypeScript are "open", and you can add a property to a type without making it incompatible.  Thus in

  ```
  interface Foo {a: string}
  interface Bar extends Foo {b: string}
  ```

  a value of the `Bar` type (`{a: string, b: string}`) is also assignable to the `Foo` type (`{a: string}`).  If you take that to its logical conclusion, any object type at all will be assignable to the empty object type `{}`.  In addition, primitive types like `string` and `number` are considered assignable to object types if their properties are compatible.  Since `string` and `number` types do have properties (like `length` and `toFixed`, etc) they are also assignable to the empty object type.  Only `null` and `undefined` actually throw runtime errors when you try to read properties from them, so those two values are not considered assignable to `{}`.

---

If you want to do recursive mapped types, you should decide what you'd like to see happen when you hit a function-typed property, and then use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to make that happen.  The obvious thing to do is just keep the method function type as-is (although maybe the method's *presence* should be optional?  not sure.)

So that would look like

```
type DeepPartial2<T> = T extends Function ? T : {
  [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial2<T[K]>
}

interface Foo {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  yell(): void,
  friend: Foo
}

type DPFoo = DeepPartial2<Foo>;
/*
type DPFoo = {
    name?: string | undefined;
    age?: number | undefined;
    yell?: (() => void) | undefined;
    friend?: DPFoo | undefined;
}
*/
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIAitbQAoEMBO4CWGAbAJgB4AVAPngF54z5YAPcWAOwBMBneAMQFdWAYzwB7VvAD8deAC54Ab1Dx4AbQDS8XOIDWsSCIBmdALoS5yVJhz5i5dcYqgAvqFBaWWAxkEIeIkQpK8KwYALawcpzgWFoA5gA0QRixEcF8oQBGsFiJIMqQsAQEABQAlHIAbiK47LnKBjFs7HJ+Is6uIFBwSGitNEgo6Nh4hKStFADcoAD0AFQQMAiIvf79innKwWGwZvBRMayx8AA+8ALssAZasOxTG8rJO3Ks6VlYJ2ccl9e3QfmFBF2xTKNCoVRqpQ+52+rBud028AauCau2WfVO0KusN+IBcIFm0yAA)